# Reverting back to Unity (Unity 7)

Tags: unity, mir, unity8

I think I messed up my Ubuntu 12.04. I really just want the 'dodge over window' feature that's why I followed the steps here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/unity-revamped-ppa-is-back-for-ubuntu.html

And now I have unity version 5.18

But every time I log in, I'm just getting a screen with my wallpaper and a mouse. 

I enabled 'unity plugin' in ccsm, but didn't work.

I tried to uninstall unity and did these:

#### sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

#### sudo ppa-purge ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped

#### sudo apt-get update

#### sudo apt-get install unity

but still getting version 5.18. Now I'm thinking the best solution (I think?) is to completely remove unity and all it's components to get version 5.10.

Or if you have a different solution just for me to get back my desktop would be great.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest is `unity 5.18.0-0ubuntu2`, so that's what you'd get after updating the system. The question is if you still get the undesired behaviour.

If what you have is the PPA-provided unity 5.18, maybe you could try changing your last command to:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

so you get the Ubuntu version of the package to substitute the one from the PPA.

I do not know how safe it would be to purge the ppa-provided package first, but sure it sounds too dangerous to try unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: if this didn't work, then i'll just re-install ubuntu (for the 4th time). thanks dude. =)

Answer (score 0):

found this question because of the same thing happening to me, so for anyone visiting this question you can also run the following:

`sudo sed -i s/XSession.*/XSession=ubuntu/ /var/lib/AccountsService/users/USERNAME`

where USERNAME is your the username of the account, in my case since my account is `/home/cyrex` I would use:

`sudo sed -i s/XSession.*/XSession=ubuntu/ /var/lib/AccountsService/users/cyrex`

What this would do is change the current default Session from the Mir (Unity8) to the default Unity one. Before doing this, the value for the XSession variable was something like `unity8-mir-default` (I might be wrong with the name), after running this, the value should now be set to `ubuntu`. Then simply reboot and you should now see the default Unity running.

All session values can be found in `/usr/share/xsessions/` with a .desktop attached to them, so for unity (Unity 3D) you should see `ubuntu.desktop`. The name of the session would be `ubuntu` and this would be the value you would use on the SED script above. So if you wanted to use for example lxde.ubuntu, you would change the part in the SED script from `ubuntu` to `lxde`.